# Cosa vuol dire arrovellarsi in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Il paese*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> – Ora piantatela, – disse Paco e gridò verso il retro per un’altra bottiglia.
>         – Ho sentito ordinare un’altra bottiglia, – disse rapido il medico. – Chi la paga? 
>         – Chi l’ha comandata, no? – fece Paco: – Io, quello che ha corso il rischio di diventar tuo cognato. 
>         Venne la proprietaria in persona, a sturare e mescere. – Ginna, – le disse il falegname: – sapevi che ti amavo, ma mi hai preferito Fresco.
>         – E ben contenta che sono, – disse l’ostessa, malgrado l’età scartando agilmente la mano del falegname che le insidiava il deretano. – Tocca tua moglie, Gino. La tocchi troppo poco, Gino, e c’è rischio che si faccia toccare da altri.
>         They all chuckled e Gino disse: – Me ne frego, è ormai arrivata all’età che possiamo fare tutt’e due i comunisti.
>         – Tieni la bocca chiusa, Gino, – disse Paco con molta attenzione.
>         – Del resto, dici e non pensi, – aggiunse il medico.
>         – Dico e penso, invece, – fece Gino **arrovellandosi** col bicchiere.

Dovete sapere che, in questo racconto, Fenoglio scrive di tanto in tanto qualcosa in inglese.

Malgrado abbia cercato il verbo "arrovellare" in parecchi dizionari, non riesco a capire cosa possa significare "arrovellandosi col bicchiere". Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prendo questo significato dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arrovellare/):

> 2. rifl. a. Rodersi internamente, arrabbiarsi, stizzirsi:

Nel brano proposto significa che il personaggio è stizzito per la conversazione che evidentemente non gradisce e questo suo stato d'animo è manifesto dal modo in cui tiene in mano il bicchiere, probabilmente nella scena sta giocherellando con questo oggetto in modo nervoso.

Comment: Può darsi che l'assonanza con *rotolando* abbia una parte.

Comment: @egreg: Avrebbe senso dire "rotolando" in questo contesto?